# How do you solve or approximate equations symbolically like $\alpha^tA_{0} = r_{0}[1-e^{-\gamma t}]$ for t?

Tags: roots, approximation

This equation showed up while I was studying an algorithm and even though it's simple-looking, it doesn't seem to be in the simple-to-solve category.

**I'm not a mathematician so I did what every self-respecting engineer would do :**

(1) I went to Wolfram Alpha : no success

(2) Used pen and paper to see if I would get an aha! moment : no success

(3) Went to my whiteboard thinking the outcome would be different : **no comment**

(4) Explored the equation graphically to figure out if and when it is solvable : success

(5) Used Maple to try to do what I wanted Wolfram Alpha to do : no success

**Then I tried more serious things (please don't judge) :**

(6) I tried to approximate the LHS of the equation with an exponential term  hoping it would allow me to take one further step with the RHS : no success

(7) I sampled the constants randomly (1E3) and generated an array of numerical solutions to which I tried to fit different hyperplanes of some sorts : no success

(8) I sampled 1E6 solutions randomly and tried to see if I could make some statistical statement about them. The only thing that came out -- and this could simply be the result of the bounds I set on the variables -- is that the solution is often between 0 and 1, which isn't really surprising given the nature of the functions : no success

**Things I thought about but didn't do because they provided no insight :**

(8) Take the dataset generated in (7, 8) to train a neural net and see how good it could get while keeping a reasonably compact structure

**---**

There you have it. The reason why this is of interest to me is that I'm trying to make a statistical statement about the workings of a stochastic optimization algorithm and it would help to know more about the nature of the solution to this equation.

I would appreciate any sort of insights you might have, references you can point me to or magic tricks.

**PS. I investigated the Lambert W function, because it " feels " like it could be what I'm looking for, but I'm still on that.**

Thanks !

**EDIT :**

(1) As mentioned in the comments, the constants have to be positive with $t\,\epsilon\,[0,\infty)$ and $\alpha\,\epsilon\,(0,1)$

(2) Claude Leibovici has already did all of the leg work so far. The only thing still left to be figured out is the case when $0<\alpha<1$. Here is graphical proof that a solution exists in that case :

[Example of graphical sln when $\alpha=0.9,\,A_{0},\,r=2,\,\gamma=0.5$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Pv5.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the zero's of function
$$f(t)=A \alpha ^t-r \left(1-e^{-\gamma  t}\right)$$ which, I am afraid, will not show analytical solution even using special functions. More than likely, you will need some numerical methods.

The simplest form we could have is probably (let $A\alpha ^t=x$) 
$$\color{blue}{g(x)=x-a \left(1-x^{b}\right)}\qquad\text{where}\qquad \color{blue}{a=\frac {r} {A}}\qquad\text{and}\qquad \color{blue}{b=-\frac{\gamma }{\log (\alpha )}}$$ which, in some very particular cases, could reduce to a polynomial in $x$ (case that we shall forget). Notice that we went from three to two parameters.

My feeling is that, under this form, Newton method would work like a charm.

You must take care that the equation can have $0$, $1$ or $2$ solutions.

This analysis could go further if, at least, you precise if parameters $(A,\alpha,\gamma)$ are positive or negative.

**Edit**

Concerning the number of solutions, back to $f(t)$, we have
$$f'(t)=A \log (\alpha ) \alpha ^t-\gamma  r e^{-\gamma  t}$$
$$f''(t)=A \log ^2(\alpha ) \alpha ^t+\gamma ^2 r e^{-\gamma  t}$$
Assuming that the three parameters are positive (as said in comments), then $\forall t$, $f''(t) >0$.

The first derivative cancels at
$$t_*=-\frac{\log \left(\frac{A \log (\alpha )}{\gamma\,  r}\right)}{\log (\alpha )+\gamma }$$ which in the real domain, will exist only if $\alpha >1$. If $t_*$ exits and $t_*>0$, the point corresponds to a minimum by the second derivative test.

So,

- if $f(t_*) > 0$, no solution
- if $f(t_*) = 0$, a double root
- if $f(t_*) < 0$, two possible solutions $t_1 < t_*$ and $t_2 > t_*$
- if $t_*$ does not exist, one solution

Comment: Thank you for your answer Claude. Two follow-up questions if I may. (1) How can you immediately tell that the eqn can have 0,1 or 2 slns ? With my limited background, I can kind of play around with it to figure out that $b = 0$, so $\gamma = 0$, leads to 1 sln, $\gamma = \infty$ leads to 0 sln, but I had to plot $a = 1$ for different values of $b$ to see the 2 slns. What was your thought process ? (2) The restrictions you mention are true, I just forgot to add them. They all have to be greater than zero except for the variable $t\,\epsilon\,[0,\infty)$. Thanks again.

Comment: @IaNick. Is my edit making things better for you ?

Comment: Thank you Claude, this is already more than I could ask for. The only puzzle left is that when you plot both sides of the equation and use $0<\alpha<1$, you can still find an intersection between an exponentially decreasing function (i.e. the LHS) and an exponentially increasing function. This last statement is conditional on having the "right" set of parameters, but it's pretty easy to come up with a toy example that works. I get the same result as you do, but I don't know how to reconcile the two. If you have any patience left, I would be very grateful.